# Different ways of linking archive

Tags: c++, makefile, archive, unix-ar

I have an archive named `libapi.a` which is being generated by `makefile`.
This libapi.a depends on some of the boost libraries like `libboost_system.a`, `libboost_filesystem.a` and `libboost_datetime.a`
Now in my makefile what is happening is the objects of the Boost libraries are extracted using `ar x` command.
The objects are copied to build directory and `libapi.a` is generated using

```
ar rcs ../build/libapi.so ../build/*.o
```

My question is why are the objects of libboost libraries being extracted?
Can't we generate archive just like we generate shared library using the below command with out extracting out any objects of boost library?

```
g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(OBJS) -static -o libapi.a \
    /home/boost/libboost_datetime.a /home/boost/libboost_filesystem.a \
    /home/boost/libboost_system.a -I/home/boost/
```

Comment: yes you can, you'll have to ask the author of your makefile why they did that

Comment: Its a very old code author is not there. So we can do it in both ways right?

Comment: I can't think of a good reason not to just link straight to the `.a` files

Comment: The term 'stripped' has specific (but largely obsolete) connotations — see the `strip` program.  I think you mean 'extracted' (because `ar x` extracts files from an archive), so I've edited the text to match that.

Comment: Using `ar` to build `libapi.so` does not make `libapi.so` into a shared library; it is still a static archive library, but it is one that has a misleading name.  The linker will probably accept the file, but it will be using it as a static archive, not as a shared library.

Comment: The `-I /home/boost` option at the end of the proposed linker command is unlikely to be useful or used (though it does no harm beyond puzzling the onlookers).  The `-I` option affects the preprocessor, and there's no preprocessing done in that command line.  Using `-L /home/boost` before the libraries would permit you to use `-L /home/boost -lboost_datetime -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system` to specify the libraries.

Comment: The 'advantage' to including the Boost library object files in the `libapi.a` library is that you only need to link with `-L /home/for/libapi -lapi` (or `/home/for/libapi/libapi.a`) and all the necessary other code is found without needing to worry about where it is installed.  The disadvantage is that updating the Boost libraries means you need to rebuild the `libapi.a` file and then relink your executables (whereas if the Boost libraries are separate, then you only need to relink your executables).  It also makes the build (link) lines more complex — more verbiage on them.

Comment: If you used shared libraries for the Boost libraries, you would not even need to relink your executables when the Boost libraries are updated (unless there was a breaking change in the Boost libraries, which is rare though probably not impossible).

Comment: The `-static -o libapi.a …` part would create an 'executable' (or attempt to create one) called `libapi.a`; it would not be either a shared object or a static library.  The linker does not produce static libraries — it only consumes them.  The 'attempt' would likely fail because there'd be no `main()` function in the libraries.  Although there are libraries that include a `main()` function (Lex and Yacc libraries did, in times past), they're rare.  If you want a static library to automatically reference other libraries, you probably need [`libtool`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/).

Comment: So inorder to generate an archive, we need to use `ar` utility itself? But in case of shared object no need of `ar` the `linker` will do the job? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: A shared library is NOT the same thing is a static library.  They look kind of similar on the surface but they are _totally_ different things and are created in totally different ways.  Static libraries are created with ar: they're simply a concatenated list of object files (kind of like a glorified tar file).  Shared libraries are actual executable entities that are created with the linker, like a program would be.  Symbols are resolved, optimizations are applied, etc. etc.  They have to be created with the linker, as a result of that.

Comment: Yes; static libraries are created with `ar` but shared objects are created via the linker.