# Different ways to generate a shared library

Tags: linker, g++, shared-libraries, archive, unix-ar

I have a source code which depends on some boost libraries like `filesystem`, `system`, `datetime`. I want to create a shared library(`libapi.so`). Since this `so` will be given to clients, I don't want a dependency on the boost to be carried by the client.
So I googled on different ways to resolve the dependency and I was able to  come up with 2 approaches.

First one is to extract all the objects from `boostfilesystem.a` , `boostsystem.a`, `boostdatetime.a` using `ar x` and copying to build directory. Now i can run the below command to generate the shared library.

```
g++ -m32 ../build/*.o -shared -o ../build/lib/libapi.so
```

Second one is to use `--whole_archive` option which compiler provides. Now the command becomes.

```
g++ -m32 ../build/*.o -shared -o ../build/lib/libapi.so -Wl,--whole-archive \
../boost/libboost_filesystem.a ../boost/libboost_system.a \
../boost/libboost_datetime.a  -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Now both the commands generate the shared library and Test utility seems to be working.

1. I want know what is difference between these two ways?
2. Out of the 2 which one is recommended/preferred for generating the shared library?

Comment: Closely related to, but different from, [Different ways of linking archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57585823/different-ways-of-linking-archive).

Comment: What happens if a user of your `libapi.so` wants to use the Boost libraries too, but is using a different version of the Boost libraries?  Does it matter whether your library is listed before the local Boost libraries, or vice versa?  I'm not wholly convinced by either solution.

Comment: That is the whole point. The user will have different version of boost may be 1.7. But we are using 1.5. So we don't want that dependency to be held by the user. That is the reason we are adding the archive itself in libapi.so

Comment: Does Boost automatically include the version number as part of the name of the functions that are called?  If so, then it helps; if not, then you end up with linkage conflicts.

Comment: I am not sure about that. Yes to avoid linkage conflicts, i am adding the whole archive into the shared object.

Comment: If i run `ldd` on the shared library. There is no dependency on boost and i am not linking boost as a shared library. So this should work right.

Comment: My question relates to this scenario: • Your `libapi.so` uses Boost::DateTime library version 1.5 • There is a function that you reference in your code as `Boost::DateTime::magical_function()` • In library version 1.5, it does a different job from the function with the same name in library version 1.7 • Your client uses your library and the version 1.7 library • Does Boost automatically build the version number into the linked name (`Boost::DateTime::magical_function_1_5()` and `Boost::DateTime::magical_function_1_7()`) so that the library versions don't conflict or does it use the same name?

Comment: There are a number of ways Boost can ensure this isn't a problem (such as ensure stable interface and base functionality across versions — using a new name if the functionality changes), or using macros to wrap the function names so that a version number is included, or using a version-numbered namespace, or ….  It may all be a red herring (that's being vigorously chased) because this is tagged [tag:c++] and not [tag:c].  It's a main reason I'm commenting and not answering; I'm not sure whether what I've spouted is remotely relevant.